# Getting MSExchange transport Error on Server 2003 SP2

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

I am getting the following Error messages and do not know how to fix it.

Event Type: Error
Event Source: MSExchangeTransport
Event Category: (8)
Event ID: 3017
Date:  4/29/2010
Time:  1:21:12 PM
User:  N/A
Computer: NETSRV
Description:
A non-delivery report with a status code of 5.3.5 was generated for recipient rfc822;gmelville@.org (Message-ID  <19104335.51321272561635734.JavaMail.SYSTEM@PARROT>).
Causes: A looping condition was detected. (The server is configured to route mail back to itself). If you have multiple SMTP Virtual Servers configured on your Exchange server, make sure they are defined by a unique incoming port and that the outgoing SMTP port configuration is valid to avoid looping between local virtual servers.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [KB here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555418) and make sure your SMTP settings are configured correctly.

From [here](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=3017&eventno=4853&source=MSExchangeTransport&phase=1):

> On the SMTP connector, you can have
>   any domain you want, but refrain from
>   having yours or a domain you are
>   authoritative for. The address space
>   denotes SMTP domains that you will
>   like to send mail to. In essence, the
>   SMTP connector in Exchange 2003 is
>   only used outbound, no concept of an
>   inbound SMTP connector really. So
>   having your local domain as an address
>   space is causing you that 5.3.5 loop
>   which means on an attempt to send mail
>   the destination resolved back to the
>   local server. Remove the address space
>   on the connector, and put just a ‘*’
>   there, so you can "send" to everyone
>   out there on the internet. On inbound,
>   to allow your server to only accept
>   mail for your specific domain name,
>   either on your initial install or
>   manually, you can do this in the
>   recipient policies by having your
>   domain listed there as authoritative
>   or "Exchange is responsible for mail
>   delivery to this organization".

Answer (score 0):

Have you been playing with automatic forwarding of mail for this user recently?

Once before I've managed to configure Exchange to forward all mail sent to a user...... to the same user.

Admittedly I don't recall the exact message as it was a while ago, but it was similar to this.